# React virtual list component: Programmatically scroll down

Tags: javascript, reactjs, devexpress

I use React Grid with Virtual Scrolling. Unfortunately, it doesn't have "scroll to row feature". Sometimes, I need programmatically select a row in my React Grid and show the selected row to a user. I know the ID of the desired row, but I am not able to use `document.getElementById('elementID').scrollIntoView()` because this row has not been generated in the DOM so far.
 
Any ideas how to solve it? I need a virtual list because of performance and need any that supports grouping of items.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [react-scroll-to-component](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-scroll-to-component), it will make a smooth scrolling to the referenced component.

I use it and it works great.
[Running example I've made](https://codesandbox.io/s/wn5m2jqp18)

Comment: I tried it but still the same problem - I can't scroll to a component that is not rendered so far. I can't also reference it because it is not present yet.

Comment: In my example it will scroll to a new created component. Click on the add item button